# How to get HTML elements from websites?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to see if I can somehow grab HTML elements from websites such as "https:://www.yahoo.com" like say the HTML elements for their news.

From what I gathered, some say it's not possible with only Javascript while some say it is possible. So I would like some clarifications whether or not I can do this. And if not, I would like to know what I can do achieve this if possible.

Some sources say I can use something like this https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest .

Additional info: So what I am currently trying to do is see if there is anything new that has been added to the website such their news feed and have it on a constant check/update.

Comment: you could do a server side solution with webdriver...create a server side wrapper...and call your service

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. From where do you want to grab the HTML elements? Where does your code run?

Based on the link you posted I assume you are trying to access it from a webpage in a browser.

Unfortunately such a thing is not possible if the webpage is on another domain, due to security restrictions by modern browsers.

The only chance you've got is to access the page server side and deliver it on another url (on the same domain). E.g. if you are using a PHP server you could create another PHP-Script containing `<?php readfile("https:://www.yahoo.com");`. Then you can access its content by using a `XMLHttpRequest` (as your link describes) to your own PHP-Script.

Comment: As stated, I am trying to grab HTML elements directly from the websites such as "https:://www.yahoo.com" and have it check for anything new that has been added.

Comment: Yeah that is clear. But from where are you trying to access those webpages? Are you running a dedicated program, a nodejs script or a webpage displayed in a browser. What is your runtime. Where is your code running?

Comment: I am attempting to run a node.js script on my computer.

Comment: In that case you can work with the mentioned axios module. Or without any need for another module, with the native nodejs http request, however this is not as comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

in your html file and use axios for xmlhttprequest

```js
<script>
    axios.get('https://www.yahoo.com') // or whatever you want
      .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response.data);
         console.log(response.status);
         console.log(response.statusText);
         console.log(response.headers);
         console.log(response.config);
  });
</script>
```

documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Any other suggestions? I am very much appreciating your response and would like to know if there any more alternatives. Thank you.